# Creating a condition in a class method regarding the position in the x-axis and y-axis on a 2D map

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Im using C++ and SDL2 to create a simulation in a 2D map of an object. This object uses time-based movement, and i use mouse clicks to determine where the object goes in the map. This object has 8 image sprites representing 8 directions to which it can go (N,S,W,E,NE,SE,SW,NW).

But clicking in some points in the map, it doesnt go straight in the same direction. Ex: to go somewhere NE, it goes straigth E then goes NE to the final position. I know how to determine the real-time position of the object in the xy-axis, but i need a condition in a class method that checks whenever the object changes direction in order to change the object sprite. I have tried several solutions, but nothing worked.

It would be something like this. This doesnt work, but you get the intention.

```
if(positionX ++ && positionY --){sprite = 2;}
```

Comment: In this code `&&` uses the resulting coordinates as arguments and almost always (expect when one of new coordinates is zero) will be true. So, you want to check not the resulting values, but the fact of the change, which exist here by your code. SDL2 is not necessary for [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Create what you have in mind, let's say [here](https://godbolt.org/) and we will be able to help.

Comment: It sounds like you have a velocity or movement direction since you're moving these over time. Based on that you should be able to figure out what sprite is appropriate. `if (velX < 0 && velY < 0) { // NW } else if ( ... }` Keep track of what the direction was the previous frame and you'll know if it changes.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks a lot. That solved the problem. I hadnt thought of using the velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Retired Ninja´s comment, i have solved the problem. I just use the velocity to get the direction that the object moves at any time.

```
if (mVelX > 0 && mVelY < 0) { sprite = 0; }//NE
else if (mVelX > 0 && mVelY == 0){ sprite = 1; }//E
else if (mVelX > 0 && mVelY > 0) { sprite = 2; }//SE
else if (mVelX == 0 && mVelY > 0) { sprite = 3; }//S
else if (mVelX < 0 && mVelY > 0) { sprite = 4; }//SW
else if (mVelX < 0 && mVelY == 0) { sprite = 5; }//W
else if (mVelX < 0 && mVelY < 0) { sprite = 6; }//NW
else if (mVelX == 0 && mVelY < 0) { sprite = 7; }//N
```